# Using NLP or other algorithms to mach two strings

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

My goal of a project is to correctly assign medications. I have a large catalog at my disposal for this purpose. However, the medications do not appear there in exactly the same spelling. Possibly additional information was added or possible parts of the prescription were abbreviated.
I was already able to implement a possible algorithm using the Levensthein distance (token_set_ratio).
Because of the sometimes long additional information this algorithm assigns wrong medications, I wanted to ask if there are better algorithms for comparing strings. For example, does it make sense to implement machine learning algorithms or NLP technology? This is a relatively new area for me. I would appreciate any ideas or inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a classic [Deduplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_deduplication) task. For example, have a look at [dedupe](https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe-examples). This tool lets you annotate training examples and learns when two items refer to the same thing. It can be used with as few as 10 training sanples and has an active learning approach implemented.